# Dual listbox how to reset list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented dual listbox using the tutorial at 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox.html

One feature I have to implement is to clear the whole dual list and populate it with another set of data on click of button. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

To populate the list first time:

```
var demo1 = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox();   
demo1.bootstrapDualListbox('refresh');
```

To empty the selected list on click of reset:

```
var demo1 = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox();   
demo1.bootstrapDualListbox('destroy', true);
```

To repopulate the list on click of reset:

```
var demo1 = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox();   
demo1.bootstrapDualListbox('refresh');
```

After doing this i only see one box with all the unselected items and the other box which show selected items have dissappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by unselecting them all by calling `prop('selected', false)` on all the options, selecting the ones you want by calling `prop('selected', true)` on the ones you want, then calling `bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true)` on the DLB.

```
<form>
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="dlb_repopulate(['option2']);">Population 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="dlb_repopulate(['option1', 'option2', 'option9']);">Population 2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="dlb_repopulate(['option1', 'option6', 'option3', 'option8', 'option7']);">Population 3</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="dlb_updateopts([['option11', 'Opt 11'], ['option12', 'Opt 12']]);">Update 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="dlb_updateopts([['option24', 'Opt 24'], ['option33', 'Opt 37']]);">Update 2</button>
</form>
<script>
  $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox();
  function dlb_repopulate (new_population) {
    $('[name=duallistbox_demo1] option').prop('selected', false);
    new_population.forEach(function(option) {
      $('[name=duallistbox_demo1] option[value="'+option+'"]').prop('selected', true);
    });
    $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
  }
  function dlb_updateopts (new_opts) {
    $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').empty();
    new_opts.forEach(function (opt) {
      $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').append($('<option     value="'+opt[0]+'">'+opt[1]+'</option>'));
    });
    $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: its not giving the required output. By repopulating the list I meant was that i want to remove the unselected and selected values in dropdown list and replace it with another list completely. ie replace the plugin with old values with new values.

Comment: Oh I see, well, that's easy enough, though the problem in this case is really nothing to do with bootstrapDualListbox as such, other than knowing to call it to refresh when you've manipulated the DOM. I'll update the answer to show you since I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.removeall').trigger('click');
```

Comment: A line of code without any explanation doesn't help much...